# MongoDB - Combination of Logical query operators not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to filter data based on multiple conditions using `Collection.find({...})` method but the output is not as expected, where `userid = 6497cda5517300ca6a7e9767`.

```
{
    $and: [
      {
        $or: [
          { from: userid },
          { to:   userid },
        ],
      },
      {
        $not: {
          $and: [
            { to: userid },
            { status: "YOUR_TURN" },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
}
```

Output :

```
[
  {
    from: new ObjectId("6497cc25517300ca6a7e973f"),
    to: new ObjectId("6497cda5517300ca6a7e9767"),
    status: 'COMPLETED',
  },
  {
    from: new ObjectId("6497cc25517300ca6a7e973f"),
    to: new ObjectId("6497cda5517300ca6a7e9767"),
    status: 'YOUR_TURN',
  },
  {
    from: new ObjectId("6497cda5517300ca6a7e9767"),
    to: new ObjectId("6497cc25517300ca6a7e973f"),
    status: 'WAITING',
  }
]
```

The 2nd document does not satisfy the condition but still include in the result. What is the correct query to exclude 2nd doc?

Comment: I doubt your query is valid. Is this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IBcC9Xespj0) meet your requirement?

Comment: Yes your demo work perfectly. but why this query is not valid. I try with mongoose. could you please explain that. It seems like it is valid query right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubt that your current query is valid. You will get the error:

> query failed: (BadValue) unknown top level operator: $not. If you are trying to negate an entire expression, use $nor.

Either:

1. Replace `$not` with `$nor` and provide the conditions in array

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $or: [
        {
          from: ObjectId("6497cda5517300ca6a7e9767")
        },
        {
          to: ObjectId("6497cda5517300ca6a7e9767")
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $nor: [
        {
          $and: [
            {
              to: ObjectId("6497cda5517300ca6a7e9767")
            },
            {
              status: "YOUR_TURN"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo Approach 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JJxVS3hiupH)

Or you need the `$expr` operator and change the query as below:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$from",
              ObjectId("6497cda5517300ca6a7e9767")
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$to",
              ObjectId("6497cda5517300ca6a7e9767")
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        $not: {
          $and: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$to",
                ObjectId("6497cda5517300ca6a7e9767")
              ]
            },
            {
              $eq: [
                "$status",
                "YOUR_TURN"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Demo Approach 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dnr9gJyndBS)